# ICE failed, see about:webrtc for more details in quickblox

Tags: webrtc, quickblox, videochat

I am using Quickblox for on of my app for video chat.

For that I have integrate this in to my app as per QB documentation and demo. but it is working only in Chrome to chrome.
See Below cases

1) Chrome - Chrome - It is working perfectly both side.

2) Chrome - FF
-> when call made from chrome to FF it is working sometimes but
-> call made from FF to chrome it is not working only ringing even if i accept the call and after some time in FF console it gives "ICE failed, see about:webrtc for more details" error.

So, any suggestion please for above issue?

Thanks